# Why does Windows 7 show a different SSID?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-router, ssid

I am using Windows 7. I have a wifi router and it's SSID is `Test`, but `Network and Sharing Center` in Windows 7 is showing it's name `Test 2`.

Why it is showing this trailing `2` and how to remove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Test 2` you are seeing is a network location, not the SSID. You can click on the icon (**1**) (usually a house, office building, or a bench) next to it and rename it (**2**). You can also select Merge network locations (**3**) on the same dialog and merge your previous `Test` network location with this one.

.

[image]